# Wordpress : Pagging on a Custom post type's taxonomy list

Tags: wordpress

have this Custom post type "wp-manga" and taxonomy "wp-manga-artist". trying to show the artist list with paging . 9 artist par page. but the pagging only showing up on the first page. in the second page onwards paging not showing up.

```
<?php

        
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'wp-manga-artist',
    'hide_empty'    => 0,
    'hierarchical'  => 1,
    'number'        => 9, // Show 9 terms (artists) per page
    'offset'        => ( ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) - 1 ) * 9 // Calculate offset for pagination
);

$terms = get_terms($args);

foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>" class="tile" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="tile-title"><?php echo $term->name;?></div> 
    </a>
    <?php
}

// Pagination
$total_terms = wp_count_terms('wp-manga-artist', $args);
$per_page = 9;
$total_pages = ceil($total_terms / $per_page);

$pagination_args = array(
    'base'      => esc_url(add_query_arg('paged', '%#%')),
    'format'    => '',
    'total'     => $total_pages,
    'current'   => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'prev_text' => '&laquo;',
    'next_text' => '&raquo;',
);

echo paginate_links($pagination_args);
?>
```